# How to integrate PostgreSQL database with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api

I want to write api (RESTful) in Nodejs to GET data from PostgreSQL. How do I connect to PostgreSQL database from Nodejs

Comment: You should start by searching for it either here or on google, as it is covered in great detail everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to use an NPM package. This will provide a client that allows interaction with your PostgreSQL database. The most common is [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg). You can get this package in your project by using the command-line from your root directory: `npm install pg -S`. This adds the package as a dependency to your project.

Refer to the [Github repo](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres.) for this package if you want many useful code examples. Here's a really simple one of my own:

```
// Your Express GET Route`
router.get('/api/data', (request, response) => {
    var pg = require('pg');
    var pgURL = 'postgres://linktoyourdatabase';

    // connect to the database
    pg.connect(pgURL, (error, client, done) => {
        // query the database
        client.query('SELECT *', (error, result) => {
             // close connection
             done();
             // return the data requested
             response.json({ data: result });
        }
    }
};
```

You will probably want to decompose the code and separate the GET route from the database call. Make sure you also handle errors and validate data.

If you want a more comprehensive tutorial, I found [this one by Michael Herman](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/) helpful.